# Enable scrolling when the curser is outside the boundaries of the control

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll

I am writing a WPF desktop application.

In my software, I am using the `IntegerUpDown` control from the extended wpf toolkit.

When using the mouse wheel, It is perfectly possible to use scrolling when the control has focus and the mouse cursor is over the control.

But, Is it possible to enable mouse wheel scrolling when the mouse cursor is not directly over the control? assuming the control did not lose focus of course.

Thanks.

Comment: Try with [UIElement.CaptureMouse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.capturemouse.aspx). Then mouse input goes to this UIElement.

Comment: Thanks Dave, required some code behind but works perfectly.